# cmd.exe redirection operators order and position

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

**First about order**

The following works to redirect `stdout` and `strerr` to `nul`.

```
command 1>nul 2>&1
```

The following doesn't

```
command 2>&1 1>nul
```

Why does the order matter? How could these expression be read in a human understandable language?

**About position**

This works

```
command 1>nul 2>&1
```

and this too

```
1>nul 2>&1 command
```

Why? Any official reference documentation on syntax rules would be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`command 2>&1 1>nul` doesn't work is not correct. It works. But as usual, it does what you asked not what you wanted

From left to right:

- `2>&1` data to stream 2 (stderr) will be sent to a **copy/duplicate** of the handle that stream 1 (stdout) is using.
- `1>nul` data to stream 1 will be sent to `nul`.

The *duplicate* is the key. Data is not sent to whatever stream 1 points, but to a **copy** of the stream handle. When stream 1 is redirected, stream 2 has its own handle, a copy of the previous stream 1. Changing stream 1 does not affect stream 2

Now, lets see the working code, from left to right

- `1>nul` Set the handle in stream 1 to point to nul
- `2>&1` Set the handle in stream 2 to a copy of the handle in use in stream 1, that is, a handle to `nul`

**About position**

Most of the time the position (before command, after command or both) is irrelevant. To execute a command, the parser has to first prepare the streams that the command will use. This preparation is done *if it is considered necessary* (try redirecting `rem` command input or output) before starting command execution.

The only cases where there is a difference are when what we want to obtain from the command and what the parser understands are not the same. One obvious case is when we need to output a string with an ending digit. Code as

```
echo 1 2 3>file
```

will not send the full string to the target file. `1 2` will be echoed to console, and the data written to stream 3 (nothing in this command) will be sent to `file`

Of course, a space can be added at the end of the data (between `3` and `>`), but this space will be included in the output. If this is not acceptable, the solution is to place the redirection at the start of the command

```
>file echo 1 2 3
```

Comment: Absolutely clear explanation, I've using `1>nul 2>&1` to suppress output without even understanding it for all of my life, maybe because I've never found a better explanation. But, what about the position?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel, sorry, i forget this part of the question. Now included.

Answer (score 1):

`CMD` simply emulates `command.com` from `MSDOS 5`. The extra facilities added were applied as a "shell", encapsulating existing functionality **and quirks** to ensure that existing batches would suffer the least impact.

There are many incomprehensible decisions made by the developer(s). It seems to be a low-priority badly-supervised project, as evidenced by the poor and inconsistent spelling in the inbuilt documentation, the decision to have a leading-zero string interpreted as Octal not decimal, rather than using `O'123'` analogous to `H'123'` for hex. There's no `/u` switch for universal-date-format in the date/time utilities and dozens of other quirks requiring workarounds - all of which point to a poorly-supervised project given to a cavalier developer unblooded in the realities of commercial programming.

So - the `2&1` syntax is an add-on applied poorly to a product that it was hoped would fade away under pressure from the point-click-and-giggle generation. Consequently, it's not "industrial-strength" - yet ironically has survived for all that.

The fact that there has been little further development over the last decade or more shows its "poor cousin" status. There's no money in it because it's not flashy and by being backward-compatible, it's bound to thinking rooted ultimately in the 1950's.

Consequently, there's no commercial reason for the anomalies introduced by the post-DOS5 improvements to be resolved. The sequence problem came along because of the programmer's mindset, not considering that anyone would try to use the new facilities in any other way than seemed logical to that *particular* programmer.

Hence, you use the redirection in the manner in which *that* programmer decided you should, and there's no prospect of having that changed anytime soon - unless you can come up with a few million to finance the development of what you want, I'd expect.

Comment: Um `2>&1` [came from UNIX](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)), so if you think it was an incomprehensible decision, you can take it up with Ken Thompson.

Comment: @RaymondChen : I said nothing about `2>&1` being incomprehensible. I said that choosing leading-0 to be octal not decimal, `H'xx'` being hex but `O'xx'` not Octal; absence of universal-date-format, inconsistant `errorlevel` settings, partial `regex` implemetation and other decisions that were made - these are incomprehensible. As is the requirement that `a>&b` and `b>nul` be in a specific order rather than applying the general principle of switches and directives in any order. Those decisions are incomprehensible.

Comment: The ordering requirement is the same as UNIX.

Comment: @RaymondChen : so - you appear to be asserting that it has to be that way because Ken Thompson ordained that it must be so on Unix. Why can't it be improved? Were `CMD`'s programmers simply too dull to realise that they didn't have to follow Unix dictates? Or perhaps they acted out of consideration. Had a DOS-derived tool been more logical than holy Unix, then what - every Unix programmer would have had an instant heart-attack? The universe would have collapsed? The solution is that simple - it is so in Unix, therefore it must also be so in `CMD`? It's that simple?

Comment: I'll remember this the next time somebody complains, "Why does Microsoft have to invent a nonstandard way of doing everything?"

Comment: @RaymondChen, does UNIX have that ordering requirements in a formal spec?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel See "The UNIX Programming Environment" by Kernighan and Pike. The Wikipedia article explains, too. `2>&1 >file` sends error to stdout and output to the file. `>file 2>&1` sends both error and output to the file. Just like in a programming language, order is important, `x = y; y = 2;` is different from `y = 2; x = y;`

Comment: @sorontar: I was using H'123' as the assembly statement. It's bizarre that  Winbatch uses `0x` to prefix a hex string in a `set /a` statement but not `0O` for octal, given that variables can't be easily used if they start with a numeric hence starting `0` indicates "something unusual". The use of ISO8601 provides a universal date format - not for or by dictating *display* formats, but by providing a basis by which dates can be expressed unambiguously - conversion to/from any other basis or format being a relatively simple programming task. I see no reason for the "American centric" notion.

Comment: @sorontar: In Winbatch, the `set/a` syntax is implemented such that a token starting with a numeric character is a decimal value, if it starts with a non-numeric, it's a variable. The specific case of a token starting `0` since people normally use leading-zero-suppressed notation is used for octal, except for `0x` for hex. All languages have some variety of special construct that is supported only in that language. A COBOL programmer will instantly recognise `PIC 9AX` for example - even if the `A` has been obsolete for 40 years. If your exposure is wide enough, the concepts can be exchanged.

Comment: @sorontar: Dates in computer systems are always stored internally in YYYYMMDD format. The Y2K episode occurred because most systems had used YYMMDD format to save space. This format allows sorting to be efficient & each system has libraries to convert to & from display formats for human use. Decoration of the date is again a user-choice - whether to keep or suppress leading zeroes, the separator character, translation to a text month or whatever. Even Americans need to convert to their preferred format. There are even translation routines for Jewish, Coptic, Islamic & Roman calendars & others.