# Difference between position of redirection in "echo>&2 message", "echo message >&2" and ">&2 echo message"

Tags: bash, cmd

I faced with different location of redirection symbol (`>`, `<`). For instance:

```
echo>&2 message
message

echo message >&2
message

>&2 echo message
message
```

For all forms I got the same result. I used redirection to file (`>filename`) instead of redirection to stream (`>&2`). Also I used input redirection (`<filename`). Result is the same in bash and windows cmd.

Does any difference of redirection location?

P.S. I saw only "echo message >&2" form in books.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25562437/2861476) can help

Comment: @MCND: you wrote there "_Most of the time_ the position (before command, after command or both) is irrelevant." My question about this. When is position important? What's the difference?

Comment: Keep reading after the *"The only cases where there is a difference..."* ;)

Comment: I don't know about Windows `cmd.exe` but at least for `bash` the location doesn't matter though convention is to put them at the end. The *order* of redirections does matter though.

Comment: For Bash is no differenece. For cmd answer is in [MC ND's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559389/cmd-exe-redirection-operators-order-and-position/25562437#25562437).

Comment: You have `cmd` in your tagging. Questions about `bash` and questions about `cmd` should be asked separately -- it would be like putting a question about Python and a question about C++ in the same place; unrelated languages, and people who are expert in one will only rarely be expert in the other.

Answer (score 1):

The `X>&Y` stream redirections in the shell merely use the [`dup2(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) system call to *replace* one file descriptor, associated with a stream (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` or whatever), with another one.

Basically, `2>&1` is literally `dup2(2, 1)` meaning "attach FD 2 to whatever FD 1 is currently attached, possibly closing FD 2 first".

This has two essential properties:

- In order for this to work, the file descriptor with which to replace the existing one must already represent the file/device we want our descriptor to be attached to.
- Once we've replaced one file descriptor with another and then reopened that file descriptor used as the replacement to some other file/device, both file descriptors become disconnected.  Hence the order matters:

  ```
  foo >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

  is OK because it's basically

  ```
  // 1) do >/dev/null
  close(1);
  fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY, 0666); // fd will be == 1 on success.
  // 2) do 2>&1
  dup2(2, 1);
  ```

  making FDs 2 and 1 be opened to the same file "/dev/null",
  while

  ```
  foo 2>&1 >/dev/null
  ```

  would first attach fd 2 to the same file fd 1 is attached to and then immediately reattach fd 1 to a new file — `/dev/null` — leaving fd 2 still opened to whatever fd 1 was attached to at the time of the first redirect:

  ```
  // 1) do 2>&1
  dup2(2, 1);
  // 2) do >/dev/null
  close(1);
  // FD 2 is still open to the same file FD 1 was just before closing.
  fd = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY, 0666); // fd will be == 1 on success
  // Now both FDs are opened to different files.
  ```

Comment: None of this is wrong, but does it answer the question that was asked?

Answer (score 1):

### For simple commands

`echo >&2 message` is the only one that differs, and it differs only inasmuch as it isn't compatible with the POSIX sh specification; support for redirections in any position is a bash extension.

`>&2 echo message` and `echo message >&2` are precisely the same, and support for both is guaranteed in the POSIX sh standard.

---

### For compound commands

Redirections are only valid at the end of compound commands. That is to say:

```
while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done <file
```

...is valid, but

```
<file while read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; done
```

...is not guaranteed to be supported by POSIX.

Positions inside the compound command would be applied to the individual subcommands, so the bash extension of allowing redirections at any position within a command does not make sense here.

---

### Formal Grammar

The below is quoted from the POSIX shell grammar specification:

```
cmd_prefix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_prefix io_redirect
                 |            ASSIGNMENT_WORD
                 | cmd_prefix ASSIGNMENT_WORD
                 ;
cmd_suffix       :            io_redirect
                 | cmd_suffix io_redirect
                 |            WORD
                 | cmd_suffix WORD
                 ;
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_prefix cmd_word
                 | cmd_prefix
                 | cmd_name cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_name
                 ;
command          : simple_command
                 | compound_command
                 | compound_command redirect_list
                 | function_definition
redirect_list    :               io_redirect
                 | redirect_list io_redirect
                 ;
```

Thus, in a shell which implements POSIX sh with no extensions:

- Redirections are allowed within a `cmd_prefix` or a `cmd_suffix`, ie. at the beginning or end of a simple command
- Redirections are allowed at the end (only) of a compound command.

Comment: According to the grammer, `simple_command -> cmd_name cmd_suffix -> cmd_name cmd_suffix WORD -> cmd_name io_redirect WORD -> WORD io_redirect WORD`. So `echo >&2 message` is also compatible with the POSIX sh specification, right?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the [bash guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_08_02_03), especially the file descriptor section. the commands redirect standard input to standard error. if you filter by `2>/dev/null` you should see the messages gone. hope this helps.

Comment: I understand redirection purpose. Question is about position of this redicrection. I can put redirection before command and can put after. Does it matter or not?

Comment: for printing the message it does not. but when acting further, e.g. trying to redirect the message printed from stdout using `>` you will not be able to see it in some case due to the fact it is appended to stderr (fd 2). depends on what you need.

Comment: additionally putting redirection before means that all output following is redirected to stderr while if you place it after your command just redirects your message to stderr.