# Batch Calculation to text

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem with this code

```
:sum2
set /a sum=%Result% - 5000
echo %section%> %file%
echo %sum%>> %file%
goto finished
```

If %Result% is 5000, then it will obviously subtract 5000 from it and save to text file. But it gives me an output of

```
Echo is OFF
```

But if %result% is 10000 it will subtract 5000 from it and save the output to text file as 5000, fine...

Now my question is, is there a way I can get the output to be "0" inside the text file when subtracting 5000 from 5000?

Comment: Move `>>%file%` to the start of the line.

Comment: Read [cmd.exe redirection operators order and position](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25562437)

Answer (score 0):

Just clarifying the answer by @somethingdark in the comment:
and it assumes that `%section%` has a value.

```
:sum2
set /a sum=%Result% - 5000
 > %file% echo %section%
>> %file% echo %sum%
goto finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following:
Assuming that %result% is equal to 5000
and %section% is [MySection]

```
:sum2
set /a sum=%Result% - 5000
if %sum% equ 0 (echo %section%> %file% &echo 0>> %file%) else (echo %section> %file &echo %sum%>> %file%)
goto finished
```

if %sum% is not equal to 0 it would write the %section% and the value of %sum% right under it. And if %sum% is equal to 0 it should write %section% and the then write 0 right under it. But my problem, though, is that the output would still be

```
ECHO is off
```

when %sum% gives the value of 0

Though, when not writing the value of %sum% into a text file, and just let it Echo, like

```
:sum2
set /a sum=%Result% - 5000
echo %sum%
goto finished
```

it would give me an output of

```
0
```

I just don't understand it

Comment: Have you read JosefZ's link in his comment to your question? Good Explanation there. (Addition: `0` is Standard Input  - obviously empty, therefore "`echo is off`"`)

Comment: Is there then a way I can do an IF statement if the 2nd line in that text file is empty?

Comment: My text file contains [MySection], and underneath it a number. So if the %sum% value is 0 (or ECHO is off in this case), it would leave the second line empty. Is there an IF statement to check if the line is empty an then 'do (MyCommand) ELSE (MyCommand)?

Comment: My text file contains [MySection], and underneath it a number. So if the %sum% value is 0 (or ECHO is off in this case), it would leave the second line empty. Is there an IF statement to check if the line is empty an then 'do (MyCommand) ELSE (MyCommand)'?

Comment: `0` is not empty. An empty `%result%` would result in a `%sum%` value of `-5000` - also not empty. Your Problem is not the value itself, but the way, the redirection works. Foxidrive has given  the correct answer and the link provided by JosefZ gives a good Explanation for it.