# Batch: Why does appending a textfile write "ECHO is off" instead?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection

So I wrote a batch that has some code to check how many times it has been run by reading a textfile and then writing back into that textfile the new, increased number.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%x in (TimesRun.txt) do set Build=%%x
set Build=%Build%+1
@echo Build value : %Build%
echo %Build%>>TimesRun.txt
Pause
```

That does append the textfile allright, but it adds "1+1" to it. Silly me! I forgot to use the /a switch to enable arithmetic operations! But when I change the code accordingly...

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "delims=" %%x in (TimesRun.txt) do set Build=%%x
set /a Build=%Build%+1
@echo Build value : %Build%
echo %Build%>>TimesRun.txt
Pause
```

... something funny happens: Instead of appending my file, *ECHO is off.* gets written on the console. Now, I know that this usually happens when `ECHO` is used without text or with an empty variable. I have added the first `@echo Build value : %Build%` specifically to see whether the variable *Build* is empty or not; it is not, and the calculation was carried out correctly. 
I already figured out that

```
>>TimesRun.txt (echo %Build%)
```

does bring the desired result. I still do not understand why

```
echo %Build%>>TimesRun.txt
```

does not, however. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are unintentionally specifying a redirection handle.

---

[Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) allows you to specify a certain handle that defines what is to be redirected:

> ```
> 0     = STDIN  (keyboard input)
> 1     = STDOUT (text output)
> 2     = STDERR (error text output)
> 3 ~ 9 = undefined
> ```

For the input redirection operator `<`, handle `0` is used by default; for the output redirection operators `>` and `>>`, the default handle is `1`.

You can explicitly specify a handle by putting a single numeric figure in front of the redirection operator; for instance `2>` defines to redirect the error text output.

---

In your `echo` command line you are doing exactly this unintentionally, when `%Build%` is a single numberic digit, like `1` for example:

```
echo 1>>TimesRun.txt
```

To avoid that, you have the following options:

1. To reverse the statement so that the redirection definition comes first:

   ```
   >>TimesRun.txt echo %Build%
   ```

   This is the most general and secure way of doing redirections.
2. To enclose the redirected command in parentheses:

   ```
   (echo %Build%)>>TimesRun.txt
   ```

   This also works safely.
3. To put a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the redirection operator:

   ```
   echo %Build% >>TimesRun.txt
   ```

   This works too, but the additional <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is included in the output of `echo`.

See also this great post: [cmd.exe redirection operators order and position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559389).

Answer (score 0):

Batch file redirection can be customized to specify where you're outputting to.

`command 1>file.txt` redirects the output of STDOUT to file.txt
`command 2>file.txt` redirects the output of STDERR to file.txt

Your build value was 1, so you inadvertently told CMD to send the output of `echo` to TimesRun.txt - when you run `echo` by itself, it prints it's status (ON or OFF).

You also could have said `echo %Build% >>TimesRun.txt` and the space would prevent the value of Build from being treated as a redirection command.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) explains the 3 standard handles and how to redirect them to another handle, command, device, file or console application.

Redirection of output written to handle 1 - **STDOUT** - to a file should be done with just

- using `>` ... create file if not already existing or overwrite existing file, or
- using `>>` ... create file if not already existing or append to existing file.

The redirection operators are usually appended at end of a command line. But this is problematic in case of using command `ECHO` and the string output to **STDOUT** ends with 1 to 9.

One of several solutions is to specify in this case the redirection at beginning of the command line:

```
@for /F "delims=" %%x in (TimesRun.txt) do @set Build=%%x
@set /A Build+=1
@echo Build value : %Build%
>>TimesRun.txt echo %Build%
```

Executing this small batch file without `@echo off` at top from within a command prompt window shows what Windows command processor executes after preprocessing each line with text file `TimesRun.txt` containing currently the value `0` or does not exist at all.

```
echo 1 1>>TimesRun.txt
```

It can be seen that Windows command interpreter moved the redirection to end of line with inserting a space and `1` left to `>>`.

With above batch code the line with `>>` really executed after preprocessing is:

```
echo 2 1>>TimesRun.txt
```

Specifying the redirection at end with `1>>`, i.e. use in the batch file

```
echo %Build%1>>TimesRun.txt
```

is also no good idea as this would result on first run in executing the line:

```
echo 11 1>>TimesRun.txt
```

So `11` is written into the file instead of `1`. This wrong output could be avoided by inserting a space before `>>` or `1>>`, i.e. use one of those two:

```
echo %Build% >>TimesRun.txt
echo %Build% 1>>TimesRun.txt
```

But then the space after `%Build%` is also written into the file as really executed is:

```
echo 1  1>>TimesRun.txt
```

The trailing space would be no problem here, but should be nevertheless avoided.

**Note:** On using arithmetic operations, i.e. `set /A ...` any string not being a number or operator is automatically interpreted as variable name and the current value of this variable is used on evaluating the arithmetic expression. Therefore after `set /A` with environment variable names consisting only of word characters and starting with an alphabetic character as usually used for environment variables no `%...%` or `!...!` must be used inside the arithmetic expression. This is explained in help of command **SET** output into console window on running `set /?` within a command prompt window.