# How do you search subfolders when overwriting a file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that makes two files. It makes a directory to put everything, first. Then, it makes a .vbs file that is used to run another batch file invisibly. Then, it makes the batch file that the .vbs will run.
I'm running in to problems with this.
Here is the code that creates the second batch file.

```
Echo echo Spaghetti ^> C:\Users\*.kys > C:\ProgramData\Kys\injector.bat
```

That makes a file named injector.bat
This is the contents of injector.bat

```
echo Spaghetti > C:\Users\*.kys
```

That is supposed to overwrite any files with a .kys extension in the C:\Users directory, and any subfolders and files in them.

It is saying `Echo echo Spaghetti the directory or name is incorrect`

Comment: Do you mean it says "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."?

Comment: Have you really got a file called *.kys

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect (`>`) data to multiple files, hence the wild-card `*` in `*.kys` is not accepted.

You could use a [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop, like this:

```
for %%F in ("C:\Users\*.kys") do echo Spaghetti > "%%~F"
```

To write this into `injector.bat` by the master batch file, use the following code:

```
echo for %%%%F in ^("C:\Users\*.kys"^) do echo Spaghetti ^> "%%%%~F" > "C:\ProgramData\Kys\injector.bat"
```

Note that this works *only* in case this code is *not* placed within another `for` loop that uses `%%F`.

By the way, are you aware that `echo text > file.ext` actually writes the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before the `>` sign to the file `file.ext` as well? Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39148808) to learn how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write to several files in different locations with one command. Find each file and write separately:

```
for /r "c:\users\" %%a in ("*.kys") do echo Spaghetti > "%%a"
```