# Reading system() command error response message

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, system, command-prompt

I am trying to execute an application (Coq compiler) using C++ system() command on my Windows 10 machine. Here is my code:

`string dospath = "coqc afile.v >> text.txt";
 int errorno = system(dospath.c_str());`

If there is a syntax/type error in **afile.v**, Coq returns a meaningful error message. Currently, I receive nothing in text.txt even if Coq returns an error (I see the error message in command prompt window of C++ application). I want to read that (any) message (returned by **coqc**) as a string or text in file text.txt. I know there are ways to do it using pstream.h but am not able to make them work on my Windows machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "2>&1" in a Windows Command Do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211476/what-does-21-in-a-windows-command-do)

Comment: Another way how to output standard and error streams to the same file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-windows-cmd-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file#1420981

Comment: If You want to capture the streams (in program), a lot more code is needed: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=610271&s=4976e90ae0bfdc6c2768cb47aa334e5a&p=3754153#post3754153

Answer (score 3):

With `>>` only the output stream is captured.

With `2>>` the error stream can be captured.

Try to execute: `string dospath = "coqc afile.v >> text.txt 2>>error.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` like this:

```
string dospath = "coqc afile.v >> text.txt 2>&1";
```

but there are better approach to get the streams like in [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)