# How does the Windows command type work

Tags: linux, windows, cmd, command

So I think "cat" in Linux actually concatenates files as 2 chunks of memory(hopefully). My concern is the "type" command in Windows, judging by the name I believe it may read and write the files, to a new file. I don't know how much time this will take if it does this.

This is how its used (just like cat it combines both files to the out file):

> type file_name1.txt file_name2.txt >> out.txt

Comment: To combine two files, you may also use `copy file_name1.txt + file_name2.txt out.txt`; to append to the output file, simply do `copy out.txt + file_name1.txt + file_name2.txt out.txt`...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

No. `cat` in Linux works by reading all the files in the command line and writing them in the standard output. If the command line is empty it will read the standard input.

So when you run:

```
cat file1 file2 >> file3
```

It reads `file1` and writes it to `stdout`. When finished, it reads `file2` and writes it to `stdout` too. But, ah!, the shell has redirected `stdout` to append to `file3`, so that is where both files are written.

And `type` in Windows works basically the same, except that the command line cannot be empty (for that you can use `copy CON`).

Now, `cat` command in Linux may have a few optimizations to avoid too many copies of the data in memory, such as [`splice(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) but that should be viewed as an optional optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Like the Linux cat, the Windows cmd.exe shell type command will read both files and write them to stdout.

Unlike Linux cat, it will add filename headers through stderr. If you want the same effect, be sure to redirect stderr.

```
type file1.txt file2.txt 2>NUL
```

And, if you want to redirect stdout, be sure to do it -before- redirecting stderr.

```
type file1.txt file2.txt >newfile.txt 2>NUL
```

Comment: It does not matter if you redirect _STDOUT_ before _STDERR_ or vice versa; the order is only relevant for [redirection operators like `2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562437) (so when the redirected handles depend on each other). To write multiple files into a file, you actually do not even need to redirect _STDERR_ to `NUL`, because it would not be written to the file anyway; it might be disturbing on the console though...